# Safercracker radio buttons – show chosen on refresh of page

Tags: safecracker

Trying to show selected radio buttons (which assign entry to categories) on Safecracker page – updates entry okay ie assigns to right category but on refresh of Safecracker page all radio buttons are empty?

```
<fieldset>
<h3>Category you belong to</h3>
<p>Please choose ONLY 1</p>

{exp:channel:categories 
  category_group="1"
  style="linear"
  channel="live"}
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{category_id}" />
<span class="sub-label">{category_name}</span>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Any pointers appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you say 'refresh' do you mean: viewing the form after an entry has already been created/updated -- or retaining the form input if a user refreshes the browser before hitting submit?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but not sure how if it applies to a Safecracker form. Maybe set some POST variables in the refreshed url, and use Mo Variables to GET them. Then you can do some conditionals to check to see which fields need to be marked as selected. But like I said, this might not apply to Safecracker forms.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that, this kinda does what I need (although now as a Select Menu)

{category_menu}
  Categories
  
    {select_options}
  
{/category_menu}

from: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/